# jQuery Ajax change variable name of cache: false

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I use jQuery AJAX with `cache: false`. This adds a `'_': '[Timestamp]'` in my request parameters.

Is it possible to change the variable name? I want to change the `_` to `id`.

If not do someone know which function jQuery uses to create the timestamp?

Comment: Why do you need this? You should never need to retrieve the timestamps value?

Comment: I use it for the json-rpc id. I dont really need the id and the requests are all related to a specified user. Even if the user sends two requests at the same time there will be some ms delay between them. So i thought this is a simple way to get an unique id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible without changing the jQuery code as it is hard-coded in. Instead just create your own timestamp id using `getTime()` and append it to your ajax `data` variable like so:

```
var d = new Date();    
 .ajax ({
     url: url.php
     data: mydata + "&id=" + d.getTime();
    // rest of the ajax stuff
    )}
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/G78t4/

cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can! I just do it.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://www.url.com',
   dataType : 'jsonp',
   cache: false,
   data : { var : value},
   // Here the trick
   beforeSend : function(xhr,setting){
       var url = setting.url;
       url = url.replace("&_=","&newname=");
       setting.url = url;
   }
}).done(function(data){
    //Do something
});
```

Somewhat late, but maybe helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

The function jQuery uses to create the timestamp is `( new Date() ).getTime()`